# Catching exception thrown in AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing custom 'AuthenticationProvider'. If not authenticated I am throwing exception inside 'authenticate' function as shown below.

```
public class DelegatingLdapAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider primaryProvider;
    private List<ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider> secondaryProviders = new ArrayList<>();

    public DelegatingLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Authentication result = null;
        AuthenticationException exception = null;
        try {
            result = primaryProvider.authenticate(authentication);
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            exception = e;
            for (ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider secondaryProvider : secondaryProviders) {
                try {
                    result = secondaryProvider.authenticate(authentication);
                    if (result.isAuthenticated()) {
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (AuthenticationException e1) {
                            exception = e;
                }
            }
        }
        if (result == null || !result.isAuthenticated()) {
            throw exception;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I have global exception handler as shown below.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({NoPermissionException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
    public Map<String, String> noPermission(NoPermissionException e) {
        return createErrorResponse(e, "Don't have permissions");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public Map<String, String> exceptionInProcessing(Exception e) {
        return createErrorResponse(e, "Unable to process. Unknown error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    private Map<String, String> createErrorResponse(Exception e, String errorMessage) {
        Map<String, String> errorResponse = new HashMap<>();
        errorResponse.put("message", errorMessage);
        errorResponse.put("reason", e.toString());
        return errorResponse;
    }
}
```

When exception is thrown inside the 'authenticate' function, global exception handler is not being called. For all the other exceptions it is being called. I want to catch the exception inside global exception handler and return custom error message. How can I do that? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually verified the exception is being thrown or your provider is being called in the first place?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Here is the link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76491649/custom-authentication-providers-called-infinitely-spring-security

Answer (score 3):

The `GlobalExceptionHandler` is for controller exception handler, but the `AuthenticationProvider` is still in filter, if you want to handler the `AuthenticationException`, you need to handle it to implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and override the `commence` method.

```
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
```

`AuthenticationException` and `AccessDeniedException` have already been handled by `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. You just need to inject `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and `AccessDeniedHandler`(which handle `AccessDeniedException`)

Or you can catch these exception in filter and then handle it in filer, like `AuthenticationFailureHandler` in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

Answer (score 1):

To complement the [@chaoluo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41274409/2250391) answer:

1. Implement the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` interface and resolve the exception by `HandlerExceptionResolver`:

```java
@Component("restAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Autowired
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception);
    }

}
```

2. Inject the `RestAuthenticationEntryPoint` into your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation and use it as the authenticationEntryPoint:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                    .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

3. Now because we resolved the exception by `HandlerExceptionResolver`, we can use the typical Spring Web error handling using `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations:

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public abstract class ErrorsControllerAdvice {


    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Throwable exception, WebRequest webRequest, Locale locale) {

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication provider is called before controller exception handler has a chance to catch exceptions.

You can override [AuthenticationFailureHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandler.html) to handle exceptions on security filter chain level, look at the [examples](https://crazygui.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/secure-rest-services-using-spring-security/)

The behavior as described in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-flow-handling):

> The filter calls the configured AuthenticationManager to process each authentication request. The destination following a successful authentication or an authentication failure is controlled by the AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFailureHandler strategy interfaces, respectively. The filter has properties which allow you to set these so you can customize the behaviour completely

Answer (score 0):

As @chaoluo already said you need to implement `AuthenticationEntryPoint` and override the `commence` method. If you want to return an error JSON object you can do the following:

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    //create errorObj
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    mapper.writeValue(writer, errorObj);
    writer.flush();
}
```