# Custom authentication providers called infinitely: Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am working on a Spring Boot application and have following requirements-

1. I have two entities (admin) and (company) with separate tables.
2. I want login endpoints for both the entities using Spring Security.

What I did-
I created two Authentication providers (AdminAuthenticationProvider and CompanyAuthenticationProvider). I added them both to the authentication manager. The AuthenticationManager.authenticate method is used in the login methods. The AdminAuthenticationProvider uses data from admin table and CompanyAuthenticationProvider from company table.
**AdminAuthenticationProvider.java-**

```
@Component
public class AdminAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

   @Autowired
   CustomAdminDetailsService adminDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    //Authentication manager authenticate() method calls this method
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
      String username=String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
      String password=String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());
      
      UserDetails adminDetails=adminDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
      if(adminDetails!=null){
        if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, adminDetails.getPassword())){
            //if the passwords match we can return authentication object (authenticated(true))
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token=new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password,new ArrayList<>());
            return token;
        }
      }

      throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong Credentials");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        //We will support UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken type of Authentication token
        //If the incoming authentication object is of this type then return true
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }
    
}
```

**CompanyAuthenticationProvider.java-**

```
@Component
public class CompanyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private CustomCompanyDetailsService companyDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    // Authentication manager authenticate() method calls this method
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = String.valueOf(authentication.getPrincipal());
        String password = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());

        UserDetails companyDetails = companyDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if (companyDetails != null) {
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, companyDetails.getPassword())) {
                // if the passwords match we can return authentication object
                // (authenticated(true))
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password,
                        new ArrayList<>());
                return token;
            }
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong Credentials");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // We will support UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken type of Authentication
        // token
        // If the incoming authentication object is of this type then return true
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig-**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc 
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfigs {
    public static final String[] PUBLIC_URLS = {

        //for admin
           "/admin/register",
           "/admin/login",

        //for company
        "/company/login",

        //email
        "/email/**"

    };

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    @Autowired
    CompanyAuthenticationProvider companyAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    AdminAuthenticationProvider adminAuthenticationProvider;

    

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http,AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests() // authorize http requests
                .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS)
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated() // authenticate
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(this.jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return http.build();
    }

    

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http
                .getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder
        // .authenticationProvider(companyAuthenticationProvider)
        .authenticationProvider(adminAuthenticationProvider);

        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

```
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{
   
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }
    
}
```

Problem-

1. In case of wrong username or password the authentication providers are invoked infinitely repeatedly. (Although I am throwing a BadCredentialsException in the authentication providers.)
2. My second question is how can I intercept the BadCredentialsException in the providers to notify users of wrong username or password?

Please help!

Comment: please do not describe your code, post your code

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please recheck.

Comment: Why are you not using the built in jwt features that come with spring security that are documented under the JWT chapter in the spring security documentation? What is the point of having a security framework if you dont intend to use it?

Comment: Also read the architecture chapter in the spring security docs as it documents how exception handling is done